# Why do my display settings say laptop when I'm using a desktop?

Tags: upgrade, display

I just upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 today. I noticed that in display settings it recognizes my system as laptop and I am actually running a desktop with a viewsonic monitor. How can I fix this?

Comment: I am running the ati radeon hd 6450.I noticed that catalyst has my monitor listed correctly.I have ran system profiler and benchmarks and it names it as monitor 0 ?displays continues to call it a laptop

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report [Current Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-desktop3/+bug/970560).

Comment: lol.Marco glad your up to par.I actually think I filed this as a bug I cant remember I have filed so many.Can I take points away for ignorance?Marco,do you think this question isnt ubuntu related?I mean it never happened with windows did it ?I m not saying windows was without its faults but I seem to think this particular issue amongst many just might be related to ubuntu ?

Comment: Is this just for points here or does anyone have any answers lol

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-desktop3/+bug/970560). You can confirm that your computer is not really being identified as a laptop by running:

```
sudo laptop-detect -v
```

To help get this fixed, I suggest you update the bug report with further details, or log into Launchpad and register the fact that the bug also affects you:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-desktop3/+bug/970560